# Como sumar columna tipo Time si las fecha son del mismo dia?

Tags: sql, sql-server

quiero sumar los tiempos repetidos de la columna2 si estan en la misma fecha en la columna1.
Por ejemplo en estos datos las ultimas dos filas son del mismo dia y quisiera simarlos, esta es el query que hago a mi tabla, que le puedo agregar para que me salgan sumandos los repetidos en el mismo dia?

```
select Columna1,CONVERT(TIME, DATEADD(MS, SUM( DATEDIFF(MS,'00:00:00.000', 
Tiempo)),'00:00:00.000'))as Columna2
from Registros
where Nombre = 'juanito' and (Columna1 between 
DATEADD(wk,DATEDIFF(wk,7,GETDATE()),0) and 
DATEADD(wk,DATEDIFF(wk,7,GETDATE()),6 -2))
group by Columna1  

Columna1                Columna2
2019-03-04 13:18:49.000 00:00:42.0000000
2019-03-05 12:33:28.000 00:37:26.0000000
2019-03-06 13:44:19.000 00:06:50.0000000
2019-03-07 14:01:16.000 00:00:28.0000000
2019-03-07 14:03:14.000 00:00:32.0000000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

para que te agrupe por columna1 debes castear a `date` columna1

```
select cast(Columna1 as date),CONVERT(TIME, DATEADD(MS, SUM( DATEDIFF(MS,'00:00:00.000', 
Tiempo)),'00:00:00.000'))as Columna2
from Registros
where Nombre = 'juanito' and (Columna1 between 
DATEADD(wk,DATEDIFF(wk,7,GETDATE()),0) and 
DATEADD(wk,DATEDIFF(wk,7,GETDATE()),6 -2))
group by cast(Columna1 as date)
```